# Draw special line with js framework

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3

I want to draw a line with x and y axis like this [image].

I searched Google and have found [an example](http://c3js.org/examples.html) based `d3`. It can draw spline chart, but i can not find the kind of chat.

Can `d3` or `c3` or any others framework draw line like this? What function should I use?

Comment: That's a really simple one line chart, of course it can do that, just give the correct options and data. What did you try, can you show your code?

Comment: It seems to have multiple y values per x value, so a c3 spline won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple Line chart, Given that you provide the correct data points. You can easily draw that. We cannot help you since you have not shared your work.

Check this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-simple-line-bar-charts-using-d3-js/) for more info.